# Font head is mandatory for PDFBox

Tags: java, maven, fonts, pdfbox

I'm trying to generate PDFs on the fly with PDFBox. When I try to load a new font into PDFBox I get an exception stating that "head is mandatory". It seems that this is normal

```
PDType0Font pdfFont = PDType0Font.load(doc, fontFile);
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3260

What I'm having trouble finding out is : do some fonts just not come with this 'head'? I've tried downloading from a couple of other sources with the same result. Is there a (free) way that I can modify a ttf file so that it will meet this requirement?

The client will be satisfied with nothing but Calibri.

Thanks

EDIT:

As suggested in the link above I tried using a Resource and an InputStream to get the font

```
Resource fontResource = appContext.getResource("classpath:/WEB-INF/classes/reports/calibri/calibri.ttf");
```

and

```
InputStream fontFile = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToFile));
```

and I've also added the following to my maven resources plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/reports/calibri</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

These maven changes were based on this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

The result is the same, head is mandatory

Admittedly, I don't know too much about maven (or fonts or java...)

Comment: Calibri.ttf from windows works fine for me (PDFBox 2.0.8). Could it be that the resource filtering problem mentioned in that issue applies to you?

Comment: Thanks @Tilman Hausherr. I think I excluded the font from resource filtering - I've added the maven configuration to the original post - but the result is the same. I'm not sure I did it correctly. My ttf is also copied from windows.

Comment: In your original attempt, were you loading directly from a file or from resources? If  you were loading from a file directly without using resources, then my comment would be useless.

Comment: What you could do is some desperate measures, i.e. try loading the font in a stand alone program from the file. Does it work or not? Does it work if you copy the font from another machine? Are you using 2.0.8 or an earlier version?

Comment: To see if the "head" table is there, open the file with an editor and search for "head", or use DTL OTMaster Light. For my file, I see "glyf", "head", "hhea", "hmtx", "kern", "loca" and more.

Comment: I tried as a File and Resouce and fiddled around with them a bit before posting so I forget what order I tried things in but I will try loading it from a standalone program and see what happens. Using 2.0.8. I'm thinking I need to have a closer look at what maven is doing

Comment: The ttf file (the one deployed to oc4j) does contain this near the start:   glyf/h��  �8 �8head�%�>  \   6hhea

Comment: mine has "glyfO\ë  ÒÐ «Òheadóý  \   6hhea
­j". From W7 size 813876 date 11.12.2015, md5: 163e0fe1bd9d024064bd40d6edddff44

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turned out I was not correctly excluding the font from resource filtering in Maven. The following did the trick.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Following suggestions from @Tilman Hausherr I tried loading the font in a barebones java main method and confirmed that it worked ok there, and then went back to look at maven again.

Thanks